# A program to sort and rename photos (drag & drop)

Tags: windows, file-management, photography, filenames

I have a lot of pictures (2000) taken from different cameras and I want to order it and rename all of them preserving my order. I'm using windows 8.

I know that I can select several pics, press F2 and rename them, but It is really difficult order them in my way.

I want a program where I can view the pictures in miniature and using drag&drop I can order them, and at the same time that the program rename them "pic1", "pic2", "pic3"...

Is there a program to do these task?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is: [FastStone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm) lets you drag and drop into desired order.

You may rename in sequence so Windows Explorer will show in the same order.
And it´s freeware for personal use.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! You reorder them using drag & drop and next rename it.

Comment: I had the same problem - and FastStone Image Viewer is exactly what I needed as well!

Answer (score 3):

I use [AntRenamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer). It has all the features you mentioned, and some more.

1. First click on **Add Files** and select your pictures
2. Use the arrows in the menu bar to change their order

[image]

3. Click on **Actions** and choose **enumeration**

[image]

4. Input a pattern (Mask) and hit **Go**

Comment: In the `Add Files` dialog, do you see picture thumbnails?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Clicking ``Add Files`` opens an explorer browse window where you can customize the view and see picture thumbnails. But once the files are added, they only appear in list form

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Features.php):

- free
- Windows
- many option to batch rename, including enumeration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have this program and it's great, but does it have a feature where you can manually and arbitrarily order the files (e.g. by graphically moving them into your desired order) and then add numbers to them?  Because that is what I interpret the OP's question as, and I don't see how BRU can do this.  If it can do this, can you elaborate?

Comment: @User You can re-order in the file list.

Comment: ah so you can! did not know that.. interface is a little lacking because there is no visual feedback of where you're dragged item will go and the list items are a bit small

Comment: @User Yeah the GUI is quite raw :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt whoa, I've used BRU since, like, forever... and I never knew one can reorder in the list! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Current workaround:

- Install [picasa](https://www.chip.de/downloads/Picasa_13013772.html)
- Add all pictures to a "Album"
- inside an Album you can order pictures via drag and drop
- finally you can select the pictures of an album -> click export -> check the "add number to filename" checkbox to obtain the correct order defined in the album